# Open boundary condition for 1d wave equation with variable wave speed using finite differences

Tags: python, finite-difference, boundary-conditions, wave-propagation

I have implemented a finite difference solver for the 1d wave equation with variable wave speed:

$$ u_{tt} = c(x)u_{xx}, \hspace{10mm}c(x) = \dfrac{6 -x^2}{2} \hspace{5mm} $$
on $-2 \leq x \leq 2, t > 0$ with initial conditions: $$u(x,0) = \cos(\dfrac{\pi x}{0.2}), \hspace{5mm} u_t(x,0) = 0
$$ for $-0.1 \leq x \leq 0.1$.

I use second order finite differences in order to solve for each grid point in time:
$$\frac{u_j^{n+1} - 2u_j^n + u_j^{n-1}}{k^2} = c(x_j)\frac{u_{j+1}^n - 2u_j^n + u_{j-1}^n}{h^2}$$

Rearranging for $u_j^{n+1}$:
$$u_{j}^{n+1} = 2u_j^n - u_j^{n-1} + c(x_j)q^2(u_{j+1}^n - 2u_j^n + u_{j-1}^n)$$

Where $q = k/h$. The boundary condition to be enforced is the open condition, so  $qu_{x} = u_{t}$ at $x = -2$, and $qu_{x} = -u_{t}$ at $x = 2$. Using the first order finite differences, we can obtain an equation for the ghost points at the boundaries:

$$ q(u_{1}^{n} - u_{-1}^n) = u_0^{t+1} - u_0^{t-1}
$$
at $x = -2$.

Next, we can substitute this into the second order equation ($c(x_j)$ disappears since it is 1 at $\pm 2$) in order to end up with our iterative formula for the boundary at $x=-2$:

$$u_{0}^{n+1} = \dfrac{2u_0^n + (q - 1) u_0^{n-1} + 2r^2(u_{1}^n - u_0^n)}{q + 1}$$

The same can be done for the boundary at $x = 2$.

My python implementation is shown below.

```
def one_dimensional_wave_solver(x_steps, t_steps):
    # discrete points in space
    x = np.linspace(-2, 2, x_steps + 1) 
    # distance of step
    dx = x[1] - x[0]
    # discrete points in time
    t = np.linspace(0, 10, t_steps + 1)
    # time steps 
    dt = t[1] - t[0]

    # define cur_u and previous u
    cur_u = np.zeros(x_steps + 1)
    prev_u = np.zeros((x_steps + 1, t_steps + 2))

    # Define mesh constant
    c = 1
    mesh = (c * dt) / dx

    # Initial conditions 
    for i in range(0, x_steps + 1):
        if (-0.2 <= x[i] and x[i] <= 0.2):
            prev_u[i, 0] = np.cos((np.pi * x[i]) / (0.2))
        else:
            prev_u[i, 0] = 0

    # Iterate through time steps
    for t in range(0, t_steps + 1):
        # For the first time step
        if t == 0:
            for i in range(1, x_steps):
                cur_u[i] = prev_u[i, t] + (cx(x[i]) * (mesh ** 2) / 2) * (prev_u[i - 1, t] - 2 * prev_u[i, t] + prev_u[i + 1, t])
            # Boundary conditions
            cur_u[0] = prev_u[0, t] +  mesh * (prev_u[1, t] - prev_u[0, t])
            cur_u[-1] = prev_u[-1, t] - mesh * (prev_u[-1, t] - prev_u[-2, t])
            
        else:
            # equation for computing u
            for i in range(1, x_steps):
                cur_u[i] = 2 * prev_u[i, t] - prev_u[i, t - 1] + cx(x[i]) * (mesh ** 2) * (prev_u[i - 1, t] - 2 * prev_u[i, t] + prev_u[i + 1, t])
            # Boundary conditions
            cur_u[0] = (2 * prev_u[0, t] + (mesh - 1) * prev_u[0, t - 1] + (2 * mesh ** 2) * (prev_u[1, t] - prev_u[0, t])) / (mesh + 1)
            cur_u[-1] = (2 * prev_u[-1, t] + (mesh - 1) * prev_u[-1, t - 1] + 2 * (mesh ** 2) * (prev_u[-2, t] - prev_u[-1, t])) / (mesh + 1)

        # Swap variables
        prev_u[:, t + 1] = cur_u.copy()

    # Return final u value
    return prev_u[:, -1], prev_u
```

Using this allows me to get an almost fully transparent boundary. But there is still some slight reflection. Is there an issue with the first order equations for the boundaries?

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a "slight" reflection. It's clearly visible. Without having examined the question in detail, I vote for error. (When I've done similar things years ago, I had really slight reflections of the order $10^{-6}$ or something like that).

Comment: 1. The initial conditions you give do not match the implemented ones, also you do not state the initial conditions outside the interval $[-0.1, 0.1]$ or $[-0.2, 0.2]$.

2. Why do you have only a plain $c$ in your wave equation, and not $u_{tt} = c{^\color{red} 2}(x) u_{xx}$?

3. In what sense is the B.C. you give the open condition? How about the simple outflow $u_{n+1} = u_n, u_{-1} = u_{0}$?

4. The image you provide looks quite underresolved, did you try smaller time-steps?

5. Related to 4: I am not sure that a CFL numbe rof 1 works here, since the max. of $c$ can be 3.